# Determinants of products of binary matrices and binomial coefficients

Tags: matrices, binomial-coefficients, determinant, factoring, continued-fractions

Consider two binary semi-infinite matrices with obvious patterns:
$$
C=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots\\
1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots\\
0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots\\
0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots\\
0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots\\
0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots\\
0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and

$$
T=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots\\
0 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots\\
0 &0 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots\\
0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &0 &0 &\cdots\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &0 &\cdots\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &\cdots\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &\cdots\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Let $A_n=T^n C$, then the non-zero entries of $A_n$ are the ${n+1}\choose{m}$, $0\le m \le n+1$ binomial coefficients. For example,

$$
A_3=
\begin{bmatrix}
4 &4 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots\\
1 &6 &1 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots\\
0 &4 &4 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots\\
0 &1 &6 &1 &0 &0 &\cdots\\
0 &0 &4 &4 &0 &0 &\cdots\\
0 &0 &1 &6 &1 &0 &\cdots\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Is there a simple formula for the determinants of the $k\times k$ upper left blocks of the matrices $A_n$? That is: what is $\det(B_n^k)$, where $$B_n^k(ij)=A_n(ij),$$ $1\le i,j \le k\le n+1$?

NOTES:

- The computer factorisation of $\det(B_n^k)$ shows that
  $\det(B_n^{(n+1)}=2^{n(n+1)/2}$ and the determinants factorisations
  have only factors less than $2(n+1)$, which suggests that the
  determinants are products of binomial coefficients of the form
  ${l}\choose{k}$, $0\le k,l\le 2(n+1)$.
- This question is motivated by the continued fraction approximation of
  the square root function, the matrices $A_n$ being the Hurwitz
  matrices of the continued fractions.

Comment: The eigenvalues of $B_n^{(n+1)}$ are consecutive powers of $2$. Please, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2886392/product-of-binary-matrices-with-binary-eigenvalues/2888379#2888379

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from the answer to [Coefficients of binomial continued fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2949151/coefficients-of-binomial-continued-fractions), since the matrices in the question are Hurwitz matrices of the continued fractions that:

$$ \det B_n^1=n,$$
$$ \det B_n^2=\frac{n(n^2-1)}{3},$$
$$ \det B_n^3=\frac{n^2(n^2-1)(n^2-2^2)}{3^2\cdot5},$$
$$ \det B_n^4=\frac{n^2(n^2-1)^2(n^2-2^2)(n^2-3^2)}{3^3\cdot5^2\cdot7},$$
$$ \det B_n^5=\frac{n^3(n^2-1)^2(n^2-2^2)^2(n^2-3^2)(n^2-4^2)}{3^4\cdot5^3\cdot7^2\cdot9},$$
$$ \dots$$

$$ \det B_n^l=n^{\lceil l/2\rceil}\prod_{k=1}^{l-1}\frac{(n^2-k^2)^{\lfloor (n-k+1)/2\rfloor}}{(2k+1)^{n-k}}.$$

The fact that $$\det B_n^n=2^{n(n-1)/2}$$ follows from [Rational fraction expression for triangular powers of 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2957325/rational-fraction-expression-for-triangular-powers-of-2)