# Rational fraction expression for triangular powers of 2

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, rational-numbers

Why does the following pattern hold?

$$1=1=2^0$$

$$\frac{2(2^2-1)}{3}=2=2^1$$

$$\frac{3^2(3^2-1)(3^2-2^2)}{3^2 \times 5}=8=2^3$$

$$\frac{4^2(4^2-1)^2(4^2-2^2)(4^2-3^2)}{3^3 \times 5^2\times 7}=64=2^6$$

$$\frac{5^3(5^2-1)^2(5^2-2^2)^2(5^2-3^2)(5^2-4^2)}{3^4 \times 5^3 \times 7^2 \times 9}=1024=2^{10}$$

$$ n^{\lceil n/2\rceil}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac {(n^2-k^2)^{\lfloor (n-k+1)/2\rfloor}}{(2k+1)^{n-k}}=2^{n(n-1)/2}.$$

The motivation for the question comes from the following two questions:

[Coefficients of binomial continued fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2949151/coefficients-of-binomial-continued-fractions)

[Determinants of products of binary matrices and binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2941564/determinants-of-products-of-binary-matrices-and-binomial-coefficients/2957149#2957149)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a partial answer:
$$
\frac{5^3(5^2-1)^2(5^2-2^2)^2(5^2-3^2)(5^2-4^2)}{3^4 \times 5^3 \times 7^2 \times 9}
$$

may be re-written as

$$
\frac{\frac{9!}{0!}\frac{7!}{2!}\frac{5!}{4!}}{\frac{9!}{4!2^4}\frac{7!}{3!2^3}\frac{5!}{2!2^2}\frac{3!}{1!2^1}}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Here we show the claim is valid for *odd* positive integers $n$. For even $n$ it can be shown analogously.

> We start with the denominator, the somewhat easier part.
>
> We obtain for odd integers $n>1$
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(2k+1)^{n-k}}&=3^{n-1}\cdot5^{n-2}\cdots(2n-3)^2(2n-1)\\
> &=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(2n+1-2k)!}{(2n-2k)!!}\tag{1}\\
> &=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(2k+1)!}{(2k)!!}\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(2k+1)!}{2^kk!}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we rearrange the right-hand side of the first line by using factorials and *double-factorials* $(2p)!!=(2p)(2p-2)\cdots4\cdot2$.
- In (2) we change the order of the factors of the numerator by setting $k\to n-k$.
- In (3) we use the identities $(2p)!=(2p)!!(2p-1)!!$ and $(2p)!!=2^pp!$.

> Now we take a look at the numerator
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{n^{\lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil}}&\color{blue}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac {(n^2-k^2)^{\lfloor \frac{n-k+1}{2}\rfloor}}{(2k+1)^{n-k}}}\\
> &=\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac {k^{\lfloor \frac{n-k+1}{2}\rfloor}}{(2k+1)^{n-k}}\right)n^{\lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil}
> \left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac {(n-k)^{\lfloor\frac{n-k+1}{2}\rfloor}}{(2k+1)^{n-k}}\right)\tag{4}\\
> &=1^1\cdot2^1\cdot3^2\cdot4^2\cdots(n-2)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(n-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}n^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\\
> &\qquad\cdot (n+1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(n+2)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\cdots(2n-4)^2(2n-3)^2(2n-2)^1(2n-1)^1\tag{5}\\
> &=(2n-1)!\cdot\frac{(2n-3)!}{2!}\cdot\frac{(2n-5)!}{4!}\cdots\frac{n!}{(n-2)!}\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=n!\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\frac{(2n+1-2k)!}{(2k)!}}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (4) we use $n^2-k^2=(n-k)(n+k)$ and put the factor $n^{\lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil}$ in the middle. We also change the order of the factors of the numerator at the left-hand product by $k\to n-k$.
- In (5) we use a more descriptive style for the expression (4).
- In (6) we collect terms to factorials starting with the right-most factor in steps of two terms. We compensate the missing factors at the left-hand side by multiplying with factors $\frac{1}{(2k)!}$ accordingly.
- In (7) we write the expression (6) more compactly using the product symbol.

> We can now take the results (3) and (7) and obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{n^{\lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil}}&\color{blue}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac {(n^2-k^2)^{\lfloor \frac{n-k+1}{2}\rfloor}}{(2k+1)^{n-k}}}\\
> &=n!\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\frac{(2n+1-2k)!}{(2k)!}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{2^kk!}{(2k+1)!}\tag{8}\\
> &=2^{\binom{n}{2}}\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\frac{1}{(2k)!}\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{n-3}{2}}\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}k!\tag{9}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2^{\binom{n}{2}}}\tag{10}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (8) we take the result (3) and multiply it with the reciprocal of (7).
- In (9) we cancel $\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(2n+1-2k)!$ with $\prod_{k=\frac{n-1}{2}}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}$ and factor out $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}{2^k}=2^{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k}=2^{\binom{n}{2}}$.
- In (10) we cancel everything besides the power of $2$.

**Note:** In order to show the case when $n$  is even we can adapt this answer starting from (5).